# Accessing Database objects suddenly throws EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

i have a problem which i'm not able to figure out by myself.

I'm using Vapor4, Fluent together with a postgres database for a backend application. (see `Package.swift` below)

There are several different models `Transaction`, `PlanItem`, `Budget` which are all interesting for gathering financial statistics. Amongst other fields they all have a date interval in which they are valid. This capability is forced by the `Statisticable`-protocol (see below)

If i now create a `DateInterval` based on the values provided by `Statisticable` every `Transaction` or `PlanItem` works fine, only accessing the `Budget` objects throws the following error:

```
NIO-ELT-0-#8 (10): EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

[image: NIO-ELT-0-#8 (10): EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)]

The only difference here is that `Budget` not directly conforms to `Statisticable`. The `Budget`-objects are wrapped inside the `BudgetInterval`-object which conforms to `Statisticable` and is passed into the statistics generator.

Now the question: What`s wrong here? How can figure out the reason for this?

Package.swift

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "backend",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.35.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver.git", from: "2.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", from: "4.0.0-rc.2"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/iLem0n/SwiftyBeaver.git", .exact("1.8.4")),
        .package(url: "../SwiftSpec", .branch("master")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Maxim-Inv/SwiftDate.git", .branch("master")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/queues.git", from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/queues-redis-driver.git", from: "1.0.0-rc.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/dehesa/CodableCSV", from: "0.6.2")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
                .product(name: "FluentPostgresDriver", package: "fluent-postgres-driver"),
                .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
                .product(name: "JWT", package: "jwt"),
                .product(name: "SwiftyBeaver", package: "SwiftyBeaver"),                
                .product(name: "SwiftDate", package: "SwiftDate"),
                .product(name: "SwiftSpec", package: "SwiftSpec"),
                .product(name: "CodableCSV", package: "CodableCSV"),
                .product(name: "Queues", package: "queues"),
                .product(name: "QueuesRedisDriver", package: "queues-redis-driver")
            ],
            swiftSettings: [           
                .unsafeFlags(["-cross-module-optimization"], .when(configuration: .release))
            ]
        ),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: [.target(name: "App")]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

Statisticable.swift

```
public protocol Statisticable: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var amountPerInstance: Double { get }
    var repetition: RepetitionType { get }
    var validFrom: Date { get }
    var validUntil: Date? { get }
    var validInterval: DateInterval? { get }
}
```

StatisticsGenerator.swift

```
public class StatisticsGenerator {
    private let latestBalance: Balance
    
    init(latestBalance: Balance) {
        self.latestBalance = latestBalance
    }
    
    func gatherStatistics(_ elements: [Statisticable], initial: Balance, lastDate: Date) -> [Date: DayStatistic] {
        var result: [Date: DayStatistic] = [:]
        
        let interval = DateInterval(start: initial.date, end: lastDate)
        for element in elements {

            switch element.repetition {
            case .once:
                if interval.contains(element.validFrom) {
                    upsert(amount: element.amountPerInstance, at: element.validFrom, result: &result)
                }
            default:       

                /* HERE IS THE ERROR, but only if the object is originally a `BudgetInterval` */
                let elementInterval = DateInterval(start: element.validFrom, end: element.validUntil ?? lastDate)
                
                                
                /* ... */
            }
        }
        
        
        
        return result
    }
    
    /* ... */ 
}
```

BudgetInterval.swift

```
struct BudgetInterval {
    let budget: Budget
    let interval: DateInterval
}

extension BudgetInterval: Statisticable {
    // accessing `budget.validFrom` throws error
    var validFrom: Date {        
        return max(budget.validFrom, interval.start)
    }
    
    var validUntil: Date? {
        if let validUntil = budget.validUntil {
            return min(validUntil, interval.end)
        }
        return interval.end
    }
    
    var repetition: RepetitionType {
        .daily
    }
    
    var amountPerInstance: Double {
        budget.maxExpense / Double(interval.numberOf(.day)!)
    }
}
```

Budget.swift

```
final class Budget: Model {
    static let schema: String = "budgets"
    
    @ID(key: .id)                   var id: UUID?
    @Parent(key: .ownerId)          var owner: User
    
    @Field(key: .name)              var name: String
    @Field(key: .maxExpense)        var maxExpense: Double
    @Field(key: .validFrom)         var validFrom: Date
    @Field(key: .validUntil)        var validUntil: Date?    
    
    /* init stuff */
}
```

Transaction.swift (for comparision)

```
final class Transaction: Model {
    static var schema: String = "transactions"

    @ID(custom: .id)                    var id: String?
    @Parent(key: .ownerId)              var owner: User
    @Field(key: .receiver)              var receiver: String?
    @Field(key: .reason)                var reason: String
    @Field(key: .amount)                var amount: Double
    @Field(key: .date)                  var date: Date

    /* init stuff */
 
}

extension Transaction: Statisticable {    
    var amountPerInstance: Double {
        return self.amount
    }
    
    // accessing this works fine
    var validFrom: Date {
        return self.date.dateAtStartOf(.day).date
    }
    
    var validUntil: Date? {        
        return self.date.dateAtEndOf(.day).date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out that the problem wasn't the database access itself, it was just the fact that i generates a scenario where the start-date was after the end date. Therefore the DateInterval couldn't be constructed.
In this case im a little bit disappointed that a `Foundation`-class doesn't check for such a common issue.

Anyway, it works if i previously check this edge case.

Thanks